# Why use s:Line instead of mx:HRule?

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mx, flex-spark

When using a **mx:HRule** or **mx:VRule**, Flash Builder suggests using a **s:Line** instead. 
Why would I want to write stuff like this :

```
<s:Line xFrom="0" xTo="245" yFrom="0" yTo="1"/>
```

instead of

```
<mx:Hrule width="100%" />
```

How do I get relative sizes ? (percent)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because mx components are being phased out for the better, skinnable Spark components.  And why can't you use width=100% with Line?  Btw, that line segment won't show anything because you don't have a stroke set.  Here's what I think you want:

```
<s:Line width="100%">
   <s:stroke>
      <s:SolidColorStroke color="#000000" weight="1" caps="square"/>
   </s:stroke>
</s:Line>
```

If you really just want to make it just one tag, you could always create a new component, call it `HRule` and have a default style to it.

Comment: Okay thanks. But still, seems like a lot of text for a simple "line" to me.

Comment: It is, but again, this is made so that your line can be extremely customizable which is better for the long run.  If you want a 'standardized' line, just create a custom component which can be reused.

Comment: @Zenklys: You only have to do it once. Make a component from it, and then use the component from then on.

Answer (score 5):

Well you wouldn't want to write stuff like that...

I would probably write it more like this..

```
<s:Line width="100%">
            <s:stroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke caps="none" color="#AF0000" joints="miter" miterLimit="4"
                                    weight="2"/>
            </s:stroke>
            <s:filters>
                <s:BevelFilter angle="45.0" blurX="1" blurY="1" distance="1"
                               highlightAlpha="1.0" highlightColor="#FFFFFF" knockout="false"
                               quality="2" shadowAlpha="1.0" shadowColor="#000000" strength="1"
                               type="inner"/>
            </s:filters>
</s:Line>
```

But it's really up to you. Any of the spark shape primitives can be written using relative positioning and sizing.

*edit*

Jax beat me to it :)

Answer (score 2):

I had kind of a bug using the S:Line element, it didn't fill the 100% inside my skin.
I replaced it with an S:SkinableContainer element like this:

```
<s:SkinnableContainer backgroundColor="Lime" width="100%" height="10"/>
```

I found it is a good solution for me, and it also saves space in the code like you mentioned you'd like.